# Spyder isn't graphing in the Console. Works fine with iPython, though

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

Here is some test code I am attempting in Spyder with Python 3.4.3. It runs just fine in iPython, but when I run in the console, the pop-up graph freezes and never displays. What's going on here??

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: When you say running in the console, do you mean doing python foo.py or doing python and then typing your commands by hand (or pasting)?  If the former, I'm guessing you're going to want to add for example import sys; sys.stdin.read() at the bottom to make the program wait for you to enter something (control-d for example) before quitting

Comment: No--in Spyder, the console and iPython are the two ways that I'm aware of to run scripts. Plots have worked just fine before, but honestly I thinking something got missed on the installation, and I am may have to resort to installing again.